# How to cycle through the indices of a vertex group in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this vertex group in my mesh:

[image]

How to cycle through the indices of that vertex group in Geometry Nodes?

This bottom example doesn't work at all. When I drag the number field the red arrow points at in the bottom image from 0 to 10, for example, I would like to cycle through the vertex group vertices in order:

[image]

Somehow the ID's or Index values should be set to the vertex group vertices again... hmm

Comment: What do you mean by 'cycle through', please? Per-frame? (Loops are not a feature of GN at the moment) Can you give an idea of the final effect you want to achieve?

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks for asking, I should've been more clear. When I drag the number field the red arrow points at in the bottom image from 0 to 10, for example, I would like to cycle through the vertex group vertices in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! The best answer came from Chanfiroly from Twitter, this is all I needed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found out one way to reconfigure the indices, but this is really destructive, perhaps.

[image]

Or, a little better:

Vertex group:
[image]

Result, I can cycle through the vertex group vertices in order (but part of the faces are now missing :(

[image]

And the nodes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I came up with, but still it's not the most optimal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more answer from Stoat Paws from Mastodon - this isn't destructive, so I like it the best:

[image]